# Device volume control buttons doesn't set ear speaker volume with audio attribute usage USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

When playing audio file, I switch the sound from the external speaker to the internal one (ear speaker). The audio is played through **SimpleExoPlayer**. Switching occurs by the **USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION** attribute. **The sound starts playing through the earpiece, but the volume of this sound is not controlled by the system volume buttons, the volume of the media in the system changes.**

I tried setting setContentType as CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH, the problem remains.

The problem **recurs** on Google Pixel XL (Android 10), One Plus 7t (Android 10).
But **not repeated** on Samsung Galaxy S9 (Android 10).

**What is the right way to make such a switch so that the volume of the correct speaker changes?**

Here is my attributes:

```
private fun setupAttributesWithExternalSpeaker() {
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()

    simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
}

private fun setupAttributesWithInternalSpeaker() {
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(C.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            .build()

    simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, false)
}
```

[Full player class here](https://gist.github.com/TheZebraz/341d2d8384749c55861bb3f0591cbebf)

Comment: Now I have the same behavior in Android 13. Some one knows a solution for it? Thks

Answer (score 1):

How about using AudioManager.setMode

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```